# Perforce submit with revertunchanged option gives empty changelist

Tags: perforce

I have a PowerShell script for nightly tests which look something like:

```
# Check out the result file
p4 edit result.txt

# Run tests (which write into results.txt)
RunTests

# Submit results (but only if changed from last test run)
p4 submit -f revertunchanged -d "Results from nightly tests" results.txt
```

This works great, except from every time results.txt is unchanged. At those times an empty changelist is left after the script is finished.

Is there any way to avoid this empty changelist?

Comment: I don't know Powershell I'm afraid, but I'd capture the output of p4 diff results.txt and test whether it contained any differences (something like is the output > 1 line). If it does, you need to submit, else you can just revert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty changelist is no big deal; you can just delete it if you want.

But, you might instead change your script slightly: just before you do the submit, do 'p4 revert -a results.txt'. That will revert results.txt, but ***only*** if it is unchanged.

Only run the 'p4 submit' if the 'revert -a' did not revert result.txt, because that means you have actual changes in it. (Another way to check this is to run 'p4 opened results.txt' to see if 'revert -a' left it open or not.)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to check if the file was reverted, or do I need to parse the output from p4 revert?

Comment: If it's no longer opened, it was reverted. So you could run 'p4 opened results.txt' to see if it was reverted. But it's probably just as easy to look at the output of 'revert -a' to see if it says 'reverted'.